# How to create in .htaccess alias to another existing subdomain with generated (routed) url?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, subdomain

I've dynamic generated URL like this: `subdomain1.example.com/example/url/2000/1000` and I need to create alias to this in this way: `subdomain2.example.com/2000/1000` So everything after `subdomain1.example.com/example/url/` should be shortened by second subdomain `subdomain2.example.com`.

How to do that in .htaccess? I don't have any experience with that, I tried to do that in my hosting panel, but it works only with real paths (not generated URLs like in my case).

Answer (score 0):

this should be done in the vhost configuration not in the .htaccess, try declaring aliases and/or use the joker flag for subdomains

```
server_name    domain.com *.domain.com
```